# Почему данные из SQLite3 не отображаются в Ruby on Rails проекте после деплоя?

Tags: sqlite3, развертывание, хостинг, ruby-on-rails

Разместил свой Ruby on Rails проект на shared-хостинге Locum.ru. В проекте использую SQLite3. После размещения проекта все данные из БД не отображаются вообще. Размещал, учитывая следующую инструкцию: http://locum.ru/blog/hosting/locum-ror-redmine

Не ошибся ли с этой командой:
$ rvm use 1.9.3 do bundle install --path=~/projects/redmine/shared/gems --without development test ?

В файле database.yml настроено подключение к SQLite, этот файл не трогал

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Какие данные у вас не отображаются? ПОсле деплоя должна создаться новая БД, на которую вы должны накатить ваши миграции.

Comment: Я делаю интернет магазин, на главной должен отображаться список товаров. Пока там 2 позиции с "рыбой". На локальном хосте они отображаются, т.е. подгружаются с базы, а на сервере - нет. Миграцию я сделал командой $ RAILS_ENV=production rvm use 1.9.3 do bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: Вы эти товары на локуме добавляли/создавали?

Comment: Так а база не пустая? Запуск миграции просто создает таблицы нужной структуры но не заполняет их. Так что после миграции ваша бд пуста.

Comment: @KryDos, а как их заполнить в таком случае? Я так понял, миграция прошла успешно, но что делать с данными?

Comment: LOL, также как вы их заполняли на локальной машине.
Исправьте, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос, чтобы он был более адекватным и актуальным.

Comment: Ну так база sqlite3 это же просто файл. Просто скопируйте файл с локалхоста на продакшен.

Comment: @1101_debian для того, чтобы их создать нужна учетка юзера, которая также хранится в базе. Так что сначала нужно решить вопрос с данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы никак не заполняете вашу базу при миграции на другой сервер.

Сушествует несколько вариантов решить эту проблему.

**Первый**. Добавить в конец файла с миграциями модели пользователя (db/migrate/_timestamp_create_users.rb или как-то так) что-то вроде этого:

```
User.create(:name => "vasya", :pass => "pupkin")
```

Таким образом после создания БД сразу же осуществится запись в базу

***Но это очень плохой вариант, не делайте так.***

**Второй вариант**. Создать свою rake задачу (task), которая будет делать все что вам нужно.

Кастомные rake задачи следует класть сюда: `lib/tasks/`

Пример таски, которая вам поможет

```
namespace :app do
    desc "Setup production database"
    task :setup => :environment  do
      # Create Users
      User.create!(:email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'passw0rt')
    end
end
```

Для того чтобы запустить эту таску нужно выполнить уже знакомые вам действия.

```
bundle exec rake app:setup
```

Данные действия нужно выполнить после того как вы уже накатили миграции.

**Третий вариант**.  Для миграции уже существующих данных данных на другой сервер воспользуйтесь gem'ом [yaml_db](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db).  Это решение работает независимо от БД, можете мигрировать, к примеру, с sqlite3 на mysql или postgres ез особых проблем.

**P.S.** Для начала советовал бы автору немного разобраться с пробелами в знаниях.

**P.P.S.** Другие ответы получили минусы из-за того что это не решение прболемы, а костыль, оч хреновый кстати.

Comment: Баш на баш - ваш ответ не решает проблемы уже существующего проекта с кучаей записей в таблице sqlite3.
Гем rails_db_dump эту проблему решает в большинстве случаев если нужен дамп.

Comment: Обновил ответ, спсибо за замечание.

Answer (score 2):

И так, раз уж суть ошибки была понята из комментариев. Постараюсь объяснить вам, почему у вас ничего не отображается.

На локалхосте вы использовали SQLite3, заполняли её, создавали миграции. После того, как вы перенесли ваш сайт на новый хостинг вы запустили миграцию и она прошла успешно. Но миграция это просто набор SQL команд, которые описывают структуру вашей бд. Т.е какие столбцы и таблицы в ней должны быть. Не более. То есть после запуска миграции никакие данные не переносятся. Все что вы заполняли на локальной машине не будет перенесено на хостинг только лишь с помощью миграции.

Так как вы используете SQLite3 (а это просто файл) то вы можете его просто скопировать его с локалхоста на ваш хостинг. Это должно помочь.

Или возможно в SQLite можно как-то сделать экспорт данных и потом импортировать их у вас на хостинге... Я прошу прощения, не селен в этом :(

Comment: благодарю, проблема решилась. Привык работать с MySQL, логика работы SQLite не совсем понятна)

Comment: Логика? Это база в тексовом файле (:

Answer (score 1):

Скопируйте ваш development.sqlite3 на сервер с именем production.sqlite3

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но он почему-то получил минус) Пока рассмотрю другие варианты

Comment: Вполне себе правильный вариант, как мне кажется. Попробуйте. Не обращайте внимания на минус.

Comment: Вам нужно было быстрое решение проблемы? Вы его получили ;D

Comment: @KryDos, перестаньте давать вредные советы. А что в случае с другой БД? Что вы тогда будете копировать?

Comment: 1101_debian, невижу ничего вредного в контексте вопроса

Comment: Вред от таких решений есть не в контексте, а в принципе. Да это рабочее решение, но я не считаю его верным. 

Это тоже самое что лечить головную боль отрубанием головы.