# Как сделать deploy:update в capistrano, не затрагивая базу данных SQLite?

Tags: capistrano, sqlite, развертывание, ruby-on-rails

Использую в проекте SQLite, когда делаю Deploy на хостинг, приходится заново создавать базу данных, т. к. она оказывается абсолютно пустой. Как сделать `cap deploy` без чистки базы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193503/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-sqlite3-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-ruby-on-rails-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F) уже был. Другой вопрос, если не выполняются миграции (если размер файла базы равен нулю), то нужно смотреть что не так с рецептом капистрано в deploy.rb

Comment: Дело в том, что база просто удаляется, точнее, она просто не сохраняется: если сделать деплой то в папке db, где она должна быть, её не оказывается вообще. А мне нужно чтобы cap копировал (или делал что-то иное) базу чтобы она сохранялась и не приходилось, например, заново регистрироваться. Конечно можно и вручную её копировать, но это как уже было сказано, «костыль».